# Contact form not work in server

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-form

I have problem in send mail from contact form. In my localhost all good working but in server I have error Failed to submit queries. Please try again later. I checked all solutions http://inchoo.net/magento/problems-with-contact-form/ but all time I have error. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Check magento log file for error.

Comment: I don't have access to log

Comment: Enable log from magento admin, so it will help you to find the real error.

Comment: I solve problem, in my server version I had additional smtp...